# How do I get my button to show once the condition is fulfilled?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is how my code currently looks like

```
sub1 = Tk()
sub1.title("Checklist")
sub1.geometry("1500x800")

def spawnButton():
    if finalVar==5:
        bQuit = Button(sub1, text="You are good to go!", command=destroy).grid(sticky="W", row=7, pady=10)

def destroy():
    sub1.destroy()

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
finalVar = var1.get() + var2.get() + var3.get() + var4.get() + var5.get()

ck1 = Label(sub1, text="Here is a checklist to help you determine if you are ready to go out!").grid(sticky="W", row=0)
ck2 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Face Mask", variable=var1, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=1, pady=(30,0))
ck3 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Hand Sanitizer", variable=var2, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=2)
ck4 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="MySejahtera application installed on mobile phone", variable=var3, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=3)
ck5 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Wallet with enough money for expenditures", variable=var4, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=4)
ck6 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Identity Card", variable=var5, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=5)
ck7 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Driving License (if applicable)").grid(sticky="W", row=6)
```

The idea is for spawnButton() to create a button when the user checks all of ck2 - ck6 (ck7 is irrelevant), which will then allow the user to click the button and close the window.

The code runs fine on CMD but when I check all of ck2 - ck6 the button does not spawn as I want it to.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The value is assigned to `finalVar` once in the beginning. You need to make it a function or just check var1 to 5 in `spawnButton`.

Comment: @Wups So if I move finalVar = var1.get() + var2.get() + var3.get() + var4.get() + var5.get() into spawnButton just before the if statement it would then work? I just tried that but the button still isn't spawning :/

Comment: I just tested. It works for me.

Comment: You should only have one `Tk()` object. The variable `sub1` looks like it isn't the only one. If you need multiple windows use the `Toplevel` widget.

Answer (score 0):

**(credit to @Wups)**

To clarify, here is the updated code.

```
from tkinter import *

sub1 = Tk()
sub1.title("Checklist")
sub1.geometry("500x300")

def spawnButton():
    finalVar = var1.get() + var2.get() + var3.get() + var4.get() + var5.get()   # add this line
    if finalVar==5:
        bQuit = Button(sub1, text="You are good to go!", command=destroy).grid(sticky="W", row=7, pady=10)

def destroy():
    sub1.destroy()

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()

ck1 = Label(sub1, text="Here is a checklist to help you determine if you are ready to go out!").grid(sticky="W", row=0)
ck2 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Face Mask", variable=var1, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=1, pady=(30,0))
ck3 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Hand Sanitizer", variable=var2, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=2)
ck4 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="MySejahtera application installed on mobile phone", variable=var3, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=3)
ck5 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Wallet with enough money for expenditures", variable=var4, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=4)
ck6 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Identity Card", variable=var5, command=spawnButton).grid(sticky="W", row=5)
ck7 = Checkbutton(sub1, text="Driving License (if applicable)").grid(sticky="W", row=6)

sub1.mainloop()
```

Output

[image: Checklist]